# Outlook 2010 keeps crashing

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook

TI keep getting this error message in event viewer every 2 week after outlook 2010 keeps crashes:

> Faulting application name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 14.0.6025.1000, time stamp: 0x4d949895 Faulting module name: OUTLOOK.EXE, version: 14.0.6025.1000, time stamp: 0x4d949895 Exception code: 0xc0000005 Fault offset: 0x00097e97 Faulting process id: 0x1d80 Faulting application start time: 0x01cf230a3e2f2784 Faulting application path: Faulting module path: Report Id: 7cdf5ed6-8efd-11e3-934e-b8763fae521c

How can I remediate this?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following: 
 - Open C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\OFFICE12. 
 - Find the dll: mso.dll
 - Cut it and paste it to somewhere else, like your desktop.

if you get access denied, reboot and do this before opening outlook. When you next fire up outlook it will run the repair tool and replace this dll.